# Drawing Table With C Language

Tags: c, datatable

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrMTK.png)

Hi!, I have a problem with the table closing. I want to close the table with some dynamic strings on it, so how to fix the table closing position?, Thankyou

```
#include <stdio.h>

char top[500] = "\xda\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc2\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xbf\n";

char border[500] = "\xc3\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc5\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xb4\n";

char bottom[500] = "\xc0\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc1\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xd9\n";

char nama[30];
char alamat[150];
char telepon[15];
char email[50];

int main(){
    printf("Masukan Nama Lengkap : ");gets(nama);
    printf("Masukan Alamat Anda : "); gets(alamat);
    printf("Masukan Nomor Telepon Anda : "); gets(telepon);
    printf("Masukan Email Anda : "); gets(email);

    printf(top);
    printf("\xb3 Nama     \xb3 %s                                          \xb3\n", nama);
    printf(border);
    printf("\xb3 Alamat   \xb3 %s                                          \xb3\n", alamat);
    printf(border);
    printf("\xb3 No.Telp  \xb3 %s                                          \xb3\n", telepon);
    printf(border);
    printf("\xb3 Email    \xb3 %s                                          \xb3\n", email);
    printf(bottom);
    printf("\xfb");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use printf with left alignment and fixed width. Something like: `printf("\xb3 %-10s \xb3 %-30s", "Nama", nama);` Those numbers are just examples - you will need to change them for your desired column widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When printing a table you need to control how many characters you print in the individual cells. The conversion specifier for `printf`(`fprintf`) allows you to do that. The standard says (draft N1570):

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After the %, the following
> appear in sequence:

> ...

> — An optional minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the
> field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left (or right, if the left
> adjustment flag, described later, has been given) to the field width.

and

> The flag characters and their meanings are:

> `-` The result of the conversion is left-justified within the field. (It is right-justified if
> this flag is not specified.)

So if you use `%100s` for `printf` and you provide a string being less than 100 characters, `printf` will add spaces so that the number of characters printed is exactly 100.

Using `%100s` or `%-100s` you can control justification of the string.

```
int main(void) 
{
    char* str = "Hello World";
    printf("| %30s |\n", str);
    printf("| %-30s |\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
|                    Hello World |
| Hello World                    |
```

Notice: If your string is longer than the field width specified, `printf` will still print all of your string. So you need to make sure that the strings can always be contained inside the cells of the table.

BTW:

You should read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/4386427)